# How to add Qooxdoo qx.ui.mobile.page.Page to Manager

Tags: qooxdoo

Qooxdoo can add a NavigationPage to the manager:

```
var manager = new qx.ui.mobile.page.Manager();
var page1 = new qx.ui.mobile.page.NavigationPage();
manager.addDetail(page1);
```

Now I want to create a Page instead and add a NavigationBar myself. The manager.addDetail only accepts NavigationPages. How to add the qx.ui.mobile.page.Page?

```
var page2 = new qx.ui.mobile.page.Page();
var navigationbar = new qx.ui.mobile.navigationbar.NavigationBar();
page2.add(navigationbar);
//... Adding buttons in navigationbar
manager.addDetail(page2); //fails: !(page2 instanceof qx.ui.mobile.page.NavigationPage
```

The answer: "Use NavigationPage is not usefull for me :)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to do with qx.Mobile Page? What prevents you from using the NavigationPage?You can even hide the NavigationBar if needed.

The Manager needs the NavigationBar, Buttons and some other properties which are only provided by the NavigationPage.

Comment: I'm trying to parse some xml notation to Qooxdoo. In the parsing I don't know on forehand whether the page is a NavigationPage or a normal one. Example:
     <page>
          <navigationbar>
               <button name="x" .../>
          </navigationbar>
     </page>
But when it's not possible to use the normal Page, I will use the NavigationPage and hide the NavigationBar when needed.
Thanks for the suggestion.